# Python -extract positive words from a string using sentiment vader

Tags: python

Is it possible to iterate through a string of words, classify them as positive, negative, or neutral using sentiment vader, then if they are positive append these positive words to a list?  The for loop below is the non working code for what I am trying to accomplish.  I am a beginner at Python so would greatly appreciate it if anyone could provide guidance on how to make this work.

```
import nltk
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
test_subset=['20170412', 'great', 'bad', 'terrible', 'dog', 'stop', 'good']
test_subset_string_fixed=" ".join(str(x) for x in test_subset)
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
pos_word_list=[]

for word in test_subset_string_fixed:
    if (sid.polarity_scores(test_subset_string_fixed)).key() == 'pos':
        pos_word_list.append(word)
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: the output is: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'key'

I tried using the .key() format above because the output from sentiment vader is in  a key value pair.  Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import nltk
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
test_subset=['20170412', 'great', 'bad', 'terrible', 'dog', 'stop', 'good']

sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
pos_word_list=[]
neu_word_list=[]
neg_word_list=[]

for word in test_subset:
    if (sid.polarity_scores(word)['compound']) >= 0.5:
        pos_word_list.append(word)
    elif (sid.polarity_scores(word)['compound']) <= -0.5:
        neg_word_list.append(word)
    else:
        neu_word_list.append(word)                

print('Positive :',pos_word_list)        
print('Neutral :',neu_word_list)    
print('Negative :',neg_word_list)
```

Output:

```
Positive : ['great']
Neutral : ['20170412', 'terrible', 'dog', 'stop', 'good']
Negative : ['bad']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. When I run the same code as above I get a different output for neutral than your output. My output is Neutral : ['20170412', 'great', 'terrible', 'dog', 'stop', 'good'].  My neutral output is the entire test_subset except for 'bad'.  Do you know why their is a discrepancy between our output and how I can fix it?

Comment: Works great now. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 4):

**If anyone wants a solution using TextBlob**

```
from textblob import TextBlob

def word_polarity(test_subset):
    pos_word_list=[]
    neu_word_list=[]
    neg_word_list=[]

    for word in test_subset:               
        testimonial = TextBlob(word)
        if testimonial.sentiment.polarity >= 0.5:
            pos_word_list.append(word)
        elif testimonial.sentiment.polarity <= -0.5:
            neg_word_list.append(word)
        else:
            neu_word_list.append(word)

    print('Positive :',pos_word_list)        
    print('Neutral :',neu_word_list)    
    print('Negative :',neg_word_list)      

word_polarity(['20170412', 'great', 'bad', 'terrible', 'dog', 'stop', 'good'])
```

**Output :**

('Positive :', ['great', 'good'])

('Neutral :', ['20170412', 'dog', 'stop'])

('Negative :', ['bad', 'terrible'])