# How to get Postive/Negative/Neutral words from a paragrah?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to take a whole paragrapgh and find the postives, neutrals, and negatives of it. I found something on the site.

Link to this is: [Python -extract positive words from a string using sentiment vader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646877/python-extract-positive-words-from-a-string-using-sentiment-vader)

However I need to do a whole paragraph, not single words.

> text1 = "Andromeda: is the 19th largest constellation in the sky.. It is located in the first quadrant of the northern hemisphere (NQ1).Andromeda has three stars brighter than magnitude 3.00 and three stars located within 10 parsecs (32.6 light years) of Earth. The brightest star in the constellation is Alpheratz. The nearest star is Ross 248 (spectral class M6V), also known as HH Andromedae, found at a distance of only 10.30 light years from Earth. The constellation is associated with the Andromedids meteor shower (also known as the Bielids), first documented on December 6, 1741 over Russia. The meteor shower has faded since discovery, but some activity is still observable in mid-November."

What comes out is typically just the letters example `Postive = "a", "c", "y"` and so on

This is the code I followed:

```py
nltk.download('vader_lexicon')
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

pos_word_list=[]
neu_word_list=[]
neg_word_list=[]
for word in text1:
    if (sid.polarity_scores(word)['compound']) >= 0.5:
        pos_word_list.append(word)
    elif (sid.polarity_scores(word)['compound']) <= -0.5:
        neg_word_list.append(word) else: neu_word_list.append(word)

print('Positive :',pos_word_list) print('Neutral :',neu_word_list) print('Negative :',neg_word_list)
```

Comment: It would not let me post this but this is the code I followed.

Comment: nltk.download('vader_lexicon')
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
pos_word_list=[]
neu_word_list=[]
neg_word_list=[]

for word in text1:
    if (sid.polarity_scores(word)['compound']) >= 0.5:
        pos_word_list.append(word)
    elif (sid.polarity_scores(word)['compound']) <= -0.5:
        neg_word_list.append(word)
    else:
        neu_word_list.append(word)                

print('Positive :',pos_word_list)        
print('Neutral :',neu_word_list)    
print('Negative :',neg_word_list)

Comment: Hi. You can use the [edit] button on the bottom left of your post, if you want to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

The [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) method splits a string into a list based on whitespace.
This will not get rid of punctuation.

To get rid of punctuation you can use string library's translate [translate](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/string_translate.htm)  function:

```py
import string

split_text = text1.split() #split into list
cleaned = []
for word in split_text:
    x = word.translate(None, string.punctuation)
    cleaned.append(x)
```

Then you can iterate over each word in the list and using the library you imported, get the word score.

```py
for word in cleaned:
    if (sid.polarity_scores(word)['compound']) >= 0.5: 
        pos_word_list.append(word)
    elif (sid.polarity_scores(word)['compound']) <= -0.5: 
        neg_word_list.append(word)
    else: neu_word_list.append(word)
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention: It seems the reason your code originally is not working is that you're iterating over a string. Your whole text is a string, so python will read 1 character at a time from it. But what you want is what is in my post, splitting the string into a list of words, so you can check each word seperatley

Comment: Hello, When I do the first fun, I get this error: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)